# convert existing html5 web to apk using phone gap

Tags: android, cordova

So far we have a web solution in html5, javascript for a webrtc solution. It is running successfully in chrome browser version 28.

Is it possible to embedded / convert the whole web solution in a single apk using phone gap?

Is the default phone gap browser support webrtc?

Please let know any info.

Answer (score 0):

well, first you need to create projects in phonegap depending on your platform, say android, ios.  Then you can start importing your web project into the www folder relatively and gradually, and see if it actually works.  depending on functionality you will have to adapt to of course, jqm or some other framework perhaps along the way.

Comment: yes i am working on that. The only issue need to know as the web solution access system device like microphone and cam to start video conference using javascript for webrtc on top of google chrome. so far i know phone gap use his own browser to launch web pages. this browser support webrtc ?

Comment: phonegap has plugins for that kind of stuff, think more webkit than chrome at this point

Comment: as i said before ;)  phonegap has already plugins for native functions, to use device's abilities through phonegap, but you should probably first try to make your web app just work on phonegap

Comment: Hi  kangoroo , As per your guide i have tried to deploy my html5 in phonegap www and did all required changes. Error message after launch the webrtc session "getUserMedia()  failed" and no camera permission asked to be turn on.

Comment: Hi , As per your guide i have tried to deploy my html5 in phonegap www and did all required changes. Error message after launch the webrtc session "getUserMedia()  failed" and no camera permission asked to be turn on. I have allow all permission in AndroidMainFest.xml as below:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />. MainActivity class is extended  DroidGap and package added  import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;  just called super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); page load but got the error.tried super.loadUrl("https://apprtc.appspot.com");

Comment: there you go, just do it you know.  hmm, you want to make sure, you are using the camera plugin though, you know in the application.

Comment: I have downloaded and configured the camera plugin in phone gap and tried many webrtc web like[link] http://apprtc.appspot.com all saying same. my question is phone gap using the default browser of the device or use it's own browser? If it's own browser is it webrtc compatible? you have any idea?

Comment: ios uses safari, and android webkit

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream according to this, it's a bit shaky at the moment